# Replace values in the result set using a select query

Tags: sql

How to replace the values 1 and 2 by "Male" and "Female"  respectively in a table while selecting using single select query?

```
Name     Gender
a         1
a         2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select  Name
,       case Gender
        when 1 then 'Male'
        when 2 then 'Female'
        end as Gender
from    YourTable
```

Comment: @Andomer is it 'end as' or 'else' ?

Comment: If you'd like to add a default, you'd use `else`.  For example: `case Gender when 1 then 'Male' else 'Female' end as ColumnAlias`